# Where to download Tor 32bit browser

Tags: tor-install

I cant find the 32 bit version of Tor on the Tor site and keep getting the 64 bit which isn't compatible with my version of Windows

Answer (score 1):

If you go to the Tor project [download page](https://www.torproject.org/download/) you will see that there is a [link](https://www.torproject.org/download/languages/) labelled "Download in another language or platform". Click the link, and from the list, choose the 32-bit version you want (Windows) in the language of your choice.

Answer (score 0):

I have a 32bit machine that the regular download seems to work fine on.
I am not sure that it is architecture specific.
Have you tried it to see if it works?